# C# 7.3+ ref variable intended behaviour?

Tags: c#

I just came across a situation that boils down to this:

```
        private static uint[] intArray;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            intArray = new uint[10];

            for(var i = 0u; i < intArray.Length; i++)
            {
                intArray[i] = i;
            }

            ref var value = ref intArray[4];

            Array.Resize(ref intArray, 100);

            value += 10; // what are we modifying here? The old memory?

            Console.WriteLine(intArray[4]); // prints 4 not 14 because the array is resized
        }
```

Is this the intended behavior for ref variables in C#?

Comment: Makes sense to me. Resize operates on the array reference, whereas value operates on the array item's reference. Or I'm too sleepy and reading that wrong...

Comment: It is syntax to make pointers type-safe.  But in this case suffers from the universal issue with pointers, they are apt to cause [dangling pointer bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).  The Array.Resize() method jerked the floor mat, it re-allocates the storage for the array.  The *value* variable still refers to the previous storage.  Dangling pointer bugs can be very hard to debug, but at least in C# they don't randomly corrupt memory.  One thing you do have to fret about is that such a pointer gives the garbage collector a splitting headache, lifetime should be very short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. `Array.Resize()` does not literally resize the array, it can't, an array is contiguous memory. What it does is create a new array with the required size and copy the values from the old array into it. As explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.8

You also have the question in the comment: "what are we modifying here? The old memory?" Yes, although you have no way of accessing the old array, there is still your reference to the element within it, so the GC cannot delete it until `value` goes out of scope. So there is no error from updating the contents.

`int` is a value type, so the value is copied to the new array. If you had an array of `Object` the value of the reference would be copied and you could still access that through your variable `value`.

Comment: In principle, an array can be resized in place (see `realloc` in C). It's just .NET that doesn't offer this (likely because it would invalidate the properties of a compact heap).

Comment: This seem to make sense. Thanks

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis - yes, that is a good point. My answer is just in the context of C# other languages do things differently, for example Perl and Python support dynamically resizing arrays while maintaining references to existing elements. In C# the behaviour described is expected and consistent with the way references work in general (despite occasionally tripping up experienced developers).